# Spark SQL: array_contains and auto-inserted casts

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We've run into an issue when migrating to the newer Spark version and totally not sure how to troubleshoot it.

We have two Spark instances, first of them is of version 2.3.0 and second - of version 2.4.0. Both instances receive the same command:

```
spark.sql("SELECT array_contains(array(1), '1')")
```

On older version, we get the following:

```
[{"array_contains(array(1), CAST(1 AS INT))":true}]
```

i.e. parameter is auto-casted to match the other one.
On newer version, this is an error:

```
cannot resolve 'array_contains(array(1), '1')' due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<int>, string].; line 1 pos 7;
'Project [unresolvedalias(array_contains(array(1), 1), None)]
+- OneRowRelation
```

Since we don't explicitly control neither the real data types nor the SQL code passed to us (they are managed by our customers), we'd like to understand whether they have to change the data or we can work around this issue ourselves. Is there something we can do at the Spark side?

If there's something we should check other then the Spark versions, feel free to leave the comment, I'll add the necessary data to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually cited in the [Spark Upgrading Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide-upgrade.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-23-to-24):

> In Spark version 2.3 and earlier, the second parameter to `array_contains` function is implicitly promoted to the element type of first array type parameter. This type promotion can be lossy and may cause `array_contains` function to return wrong result. This problem has been addressed in 2.4 by employing a safer type promotion mechanism

So in short, the implicit cast of the second parameter to type in the array was removed in version 2.4 and you have to explicitly pass the good type:

```
spark.sql("SELECT array_contains(array(1), 1)")
```

There is another function introduced in Spark 2.4 in builtin higher-order functions: [`exists`](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html)  that does the cast but it's not the same syntax:

```
spark.sql("SELECT exists(array(1), x -> x=='1')").show()
```

It takes the array column and a lambda function and it is transfomed to:

```
exists(array(1), lambdafunction((namedlambdavariable() = CAST(1 AS INT)), namedlambdavariable()))
```

As you can see the cast is done by Spark.

Comment: And it means that if it's really something like `array_contains(array(item1, item2, ... itemn), item)`, where all variables are supplied by user, they will have to use an explicit cast?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately! Unless you want to detect the introduced SQL from user and change to query by casting to correct type (which I do not recommend), they'll have to do explicit casts. See my edit in the answer too.